# "Failed to submit hashrate" error

Tags: mining, mining-pools, hashrate

I'm currently using geth and ethminer to mine, I'm using version 1.2.2 of Ethereum. I'm trying to mine on pool Ethereumpool, using [these instructions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1156674.0). So my command is `ethminer -G -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=20@0xe425AFC9cC425E88f911Ba9d4E77Eef763bCef22`

I get spammed by the error "Failed to submit hashrate". Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

#### First

> Update Ethereum to [1.3.5](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.5)

#### “Failed to submit hashrate” error

The function `eth_submitHashrate` is only implemented from certain version of the`ethminer`. And the reason could be multiple.

#### Workaround

Install a miner proxy like [eth-stratum-mining-proxy](https://github.com/Coinotron/eth-stratum-mining-proxy)

Comment: ethminer 1.2.2 is perfect for homestead and 1.3.5 refers to the golang implementation.

Comment: You only suggest a geth update to 1.3.5, but the issue is one ethminer. Could you provide an ethminer version implementing the said function, please ?